# jQuery validation submitHandler not work in $.ajax post form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have Send data using `$.ajax` and validation with jQuery validation plugin like this :

```
<div class="" id="ajax-form-msg1"></div>
<form id="myform" action="load.php">
    <input type="input" name="name" id="name" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" id="my_token" value="MkO89FgtRF^&5fg#547@d6fghBgf5" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="ajax-1">Send</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                rangelength: [4, 20],
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {

            $("#ajax-1").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // avoid submitting the form here
                $("#ajax-form-msg1").html("<img src='http://www.drogbaster.it/loading/loading25.gif'>");
                var formData = $("#myform").serialize();
                var URL = $("#myform").attr("action");
                $.ajax({
                    url: URL,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    async: false
                }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (data == "yes") {
                        $("#ajax-form-msg1").html(' < div class = "alert alert-success" > ' + data + ' < /div>');
                        $("#form-content").modal('show');
                        $(".contact-form").slideUp();
                    } else {
                        $("#ajax-form-msg1").html('' + data + '');
                    }
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#ajax-form-msg1").html(' < div class = "alert alert-danger" >AJAX Request Failed < br / > textStatus = ' + textStatus + ', errorThrown = ' + errorThrown + ' < /code></pre > ');
                });
            });

        }
    });
});
```

In action my form validate using jQuery validation but after validation not submit and not send data.

how do fix this problem?!

DEMO [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/g7ssanvr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The submitHandler is expecting a submit and you have a click event inside it and then an ajax call.

If you have a button type="submit" inside a form you don't even need a click event, the plugin will do the validation automatically. So just make the ajax call inside the submitHandler.

If you need to bind the action to a button using the click event, the proper approach should be something like this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
 var form = $('#myform').validate({...}); #store the validator obj
 if (form.is_valid()){
  // submit using ajax
 } else {
  // dont do anything
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call form.submit() at the end of your done function.

See: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Also, you do not need $("#ajax-1").click() because the submitHandler will be called automatically when you click on that button anyways. You can test this yourself by putting a console.log as the first line of submitHandler. Then fill out the form and press the button. See if it prints out your log message.

Comment: `form.submit()` not work in case. please check in jsfiddle

Comment: its not going to work on jsFiddle because it does not have load.php

Comment: u can test with `<div class="" id="ajax-form-msg1"></div>` show loading `img` before `load.php`

Answer (score 0):

In `submitHandler` you are handling the submit , then again why did you write click event?

Here is the fix.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        rangelength: [2, 20],
      },
    },
    submitHandler: function(a, e) {
      //a is form object and e is event
      e.preventDefault(); // avoid submitting the form here
      $("#ajax-form-msg1").html("<img src='http://www.drogbaster.it/loading/loading25.gif'>");
      var formData = $("#myform").serialize();
      var URL = $("#myform").attr("action");
      $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data == "yes") {
          $("#ajax-form-msg1").html(' < div class = "alert alert-success" > ' + data + ' < /div>');
          $("#form-content").modal('show');
          $(".contact-form").slideUp();
        } else {
          $("#ajax-form-msg1").html('' + data + '');
        }
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#ajax-form-msg1").html(' < div class = "alert alert-danger" >AJAX Request Failed < br / > textStatus = ' + textStatus + ', errorThrown = ' + errorThrown + ' < /code></pre > ');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform" action="load.php">
  <input type="input" name="name" id="name" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" id="my_token" value="MkO89FgtRF^&5fg#547@d6fghBgf5" />
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="ajax-1">Send</button>
</form>
```

Use `success` and `error` call backs to get data or error messages.

**Note**: Here (In StackOverflow) you will get `404 Page Not Found` error when you submit. So try in your local.